# Crawling over 1000 pagers with a single crawler vs multiple small crawlers

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to crawl a local news website, which has over 1000 pagers for each category. I'm using Beautiful Soup and requests. But, my crawler is super slow, even after running it from 10:am to 5:30pm, it won't finish. So, I got an idea which is to make mini size of the latter one ( each for 100 pagers or so) and run them in parallel.
Now, the advice I seek for is:
Which method would be less time consuming?
Thanks and Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: maybe you will not get advice because this is place to fix a code

Comment: May be so. I just want an advice though. T_T